# Edit mySQL record inside HTML Table via double click - Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, html-table, edit

I have an HTML TABLE that displays my records from mySQL.

I need to edit various records (rows).  Is it possible to click on a table row and edit the values in the row inside the HTML table?

I was wondering if there are any PHP scripts out there to guide me?

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do, but if it's related to modifying what is displayed in the browser you could quite easily do it with JavaScript (take a look at onclick event). If you also want the change to update the DB you could do it via AJAX and some code on the server-side.

Comment: Note that this is not advised, most of user agents already have their own double click behavior, some will zoom on the page, some will select the focused word. A good practice is to try to rely exclusively on simple left click. Don't forget phones and tablets for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. While I am very convinced PHP is involved, Javascript is involved also.
I think you can have something like this:

1.Click once, javascript increases a counter variable
2. Click twice, javascript checks if var = 2 after increasing, resets counter, and changes innerHTML of the td to something like this:

```
 form action ='yourphpscript.php' method = 'getorpost'>
 .....What you want to change....
 </form>
```

3. So then it sends your values to the PHP script, PHP script changes values in database, and you get redirected back to the main page. Or, better yet, use AJAX.

Hope this helped :)